# Automatically trigger broadcast event in laravel 5.2

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, socket.io

I am using BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis to trigger laravel 5.2 event. 
Once i run the following services on command prompt :

1. In the first tab, run node socket.js

   You should see "Listening on Port 3000"
2. In the second tab run redis-server --port 3001

After it Open up two browser windows side by side and in the first one hit the URL: "http://your-project-name.app/fire"

And in the second:  "http://your-project-name.app/test"

Keep refreshing the first window and you should see the second page's content updated.

But i do not want to refreshing the page , i just want to trigger the broadcast event in background and also do not want to run the services "node socket.js and redis-server --port 3004".

I have installed node,redis,express ioredis socket.io and created the event.

My socket code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) { });
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) { 
  console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
  message = JSON.parse(message);
  io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});

http.listen(3004, function(){
  console.log('Listening on Port 3004');
});
```

Comment: my socket.js code is

var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();
redis.subscribe('test-channel', function(err, count) {
});
redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    console.log('Message Recieved: ' + message);
    message = JSON.parse(message);
    io.emit(channel + ':' + message.event, message.data);
});
http.listen(3004, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3004');
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Redis Pub/Sub](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/redis#pubsub)

> These Redis commands allow you to listen for messages on a given "channel". You may publish messages to the channel from another application, or even using another programming language, allowing easy communication between applications / processes.

First, let's setup a listener on a channel via Redis using the subscribe method. We will place this method call within an Artisan command since calling the subscribe method begins a long-running process:

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use Redis;
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;

    class RedisSubscribe extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'redis:subscribe';

        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = 'Subscribe to a Redis channel';

        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return mixed
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            Redis::subscribe(['test-channel'], function($message) {
                echo $message;
            });
        }
    }
```

Go to terminal, in your root folder launch the command

```
 php artisan redis:subscribe
```

Now, we may publish messages to the channel using the publish method:

```
 Redis::publish('test-channel', json_encode(['foo' => 'bar']));
```

This method doesn't use nodejs.

Comment: for receiving end i am using the following code::
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.5.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
    var socket = io('http://localhost:3004');
    socket.on("test-channel:App\\Events\\EventName", function (message) {
        $('#power').text(parseInt($('#power').text()) + parseInt(message.data.power));
 });
</script>
And also i have event code in laravel 5.2, What next i need to do, Can you please give me some direction? Eagerly waiting for your valuable response!!

Comment: My problem is to trigger the event in background automatically in specific time interval. I have everything working but when i trigger it manually .

Comment: Pub/sub is that you need, forgot nodejs. In https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/redis#pubsub you have  the example. First create a command to listen and after send message to channel with Redis::publish()

Comment: If you want to trigger it in background, you must don't use nodejs, because is only to trigger events in your frontend, not in background. Change for the method I showed you

Comment: I will implement your solution in future and let you know , Thanks for your assistance